# Best way for a Mac application to talk to Windows applications

Tags: cocoa, networking, cross-platform

I need to write an app on Mac OS X that would send remote command to Windows applications to perform some tasks. The computers will be sitting on the same subnet and the Mac and Windows computers all have a fixed IP.

The data sent over really are just some string or boolean parameters so that the Windows app can perform specific tasks.

Someone will be writing the Windows app and I will be writing the Mac app.

I can find in the developer's doc about Mac to Mac communication, but nothing about what I need.

What's the best way to achieve this? What protocol is best suited for this?

Comment: You mean, something on top of TCP or UDP?

Comment: We used TCP in the end, the documentation seems to be scarce too. Then I found GCDAsyncSocket in google code and used that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two separate problems here:

- #1 is how you discover the other app. Bonjour is one possibility, as is a local broadcast, as is explicitly configuring the hostname of the peer
- #2 is how you talk to the other machine once you find it. For that part, I would suggest:

  - a) use TCP instead of UDP (in most cases), so you don't have to worry about retransmissions & sequencing
  - b) rather than inventing your own client-server protocol on top of TCP, use an existing one. I hear there's something called "HTTP" that's starting to catch on...

Comment: Thank you. David. We used TCP with google code GCDAsycnSocket in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Bonjour SDk for Mac and Windows: http://developer.apple.com/opensource/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did think about Bonjour. However, the Windows side programming is outsourced. Asking him to study another framework now would add cost and project time. I was hoping to find a more widespread standard that both Mac and Windows understand. Are there any other protocols available?

Comment: I also just read the FAQ on Bonjour, and it stated "Bonjour itself is simply a way to *discover* network services that use various protocols: e.g., Jabber for iChat or IPP for printing. That said, Bonjour DNS packets can include a very small amount of "text" information, as exemplified by the presence information for use with iChat." Since we can live with fixed IP, zero config discovery for now is an overkill for us.

Comment: Well, if the Windows side is outsourced and that developer has already decided what he's going to do, that limits your options to just one: Implement your side of whatever protocol he chose.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use UDP to broadcast a message out to the network?  Your apps (regardless of whether they are running on Mac or Windows) can listen for the message and process them as needed.

Comment: thank you. Paul. We tried UDP but then later decided to use TCP instead.